# PowerBI Combining Columns with the Same information

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to build a new table in PowerBI whose unique column is based on the combination of two columns from another table. Anyone have any Idea as to how to do this? In my example below I want Column A and B from the source table to make Column C in the new table.

Example:

Source Table

| Column A | Column B | Additional Data | Additional Data 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | .258 | .364 |
| A | C | .158 | .354 |
| B | D | .1657 | .1365 |
| C | B | .135 | .534 |
| B | C | .537 | .357 |
| E | D | .13 | .64 |

New Table

| Column C | Calculated Data |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6.59 |
| B | 3.48 |
| C | 0.41 |
| D | 7.15 |
| E | 5.26 |

Comment: Can you clearly explain how do you derive to `Calculated Data` in `New Table` from `Source Table`. E.g. how `A=6.59?`

Comment: The calculated data does not matter. I just typed in some random numbers. What does matter is combining columns A and B into column C. With the actual data the calculated data is a count of string data that meets a very lengthy criteria and I already know the calculation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PQWRY

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292744/powerbi-combining-columns-with-the-same-information?noredirect=1#comment120741477_68292744"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(4) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Column2", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(4) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, {"Column3", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(4) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, {"Column4", "DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(4) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR > :nth-child(4)"}}, [RowSelector="DIV.s-table-container:nth-child(4) > TABLE.s-table > * > TR"]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Extracted Table From Html", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Column A", type text}, {"Column B", type text}, {"Additional Data", type number}, {"Additional Data 2", type number}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column A"})&Table.RenameColumns(Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column B"}),{{"Column B", "Column A"}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

DAX

```
Table =
DISTINCT (
    UNION (
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 'Table', "colC", 'Table'[Column A] ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 'Table 1', "colC", 'Table 1'[Column B] )
    )
)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!!!! This worked out exactly like I was hoping!!!!! I used the DAX option. I'll try out the PQWRY at some point to see if it works well with my data. Thank you again!